# How to find out what service is listening on a specific port of a Ubuntu server without proccess id?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, port, process

I have decided to post this question even though there are a lot of similar questions, but none of them answered mine.

1. I periodically check the ports my server listens to.
2. My ubuntu OS by the output of `lsb_relase -a`:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

3. I run the command `netstat -tulpn4` and the output shows an unknown port:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      580/systemd-resolve 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:62176           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      900/sshd: /usr/sbin 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1122            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1158/sshd: username    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3333            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1158/sshd: username    
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:51820           0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           580/systemd-resolve 
udp        0      0 X.X.X.X:1194           0.0.0.0:*                           870/openvpn
```

1. I have used many tools and guides to find out why my server is listening on port `51820` without finding an answer.
2. I have tried:

   - `sudo lsof -i :51820` - and got an empty output.
   - `sudo netstat -ltnp | grep -w ':51820'` - and got an empty output.
   - `sudo fuser 51820/udp` - and got an empty output.
   - `sudo netstat -peanut | grep ":51820"` - the output is:

```
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:51820           0.0.0.0:*                           0          26262      -                   
udp6       0      0 :::51820                :::*                                0          26263      -
```

- `sudo ss -nlp | grep 51820` the output is:

```
udp     UNCONN   0        0                                             0.0.0.0:51820                                             0.0.0.0:*                                                                                                     
udp     UNCONN   0        0                                                [::]:51820                                                [::]:*
```

3. I have looked at the following answers and did not find a solution:

   - [How to know what program is listening on a given port?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/278448/how-to-know-what-program-is-listening-on-a-given-port)
   - [3 Ways to Find Out Which Process Listening on a Particular Port](https://www.tecmint.com/find-out-which-process-listening-on-a-particular-port/)
   - [How to know what program is listening on a given port?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/278448/how-to-know-what-program-is-listening-on-a-given-port)
   - [How can we find which process is using a particular port? [duplicate]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/227161/how-can-we-find-which-process-is-using-a-particular-port)

After searching the web about port `51820` I found out it is the "wireguard" I have installed that`s listening on that port, but the question remains the same as in any command I have tried I could not find that out.

Comment: related: [wireguard not listening on port](https://serverfault.com/questions/1015322/the-wireguard-not-listening-on-port-after-started)

Comment: @anx tnx for your comment, my "wireguard" service is working fine and still the answers in the related post are not solving my problem of detecting the process that cause the specific port listening by a terminal command.

Comment: then update the question to be more specific. You walk around your issue you want to having solved.

Comment: How can i be more specific? I am really trying to get answer to the question title, and i have listed all the solutions i have already tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Genreal:**

After a two days search I did around the issue, I found like Michael Hampton and Peter Zhabin that there is no existing solution which shows a kernel process id via a listening port.

In addition during those two days i searched also for some `commands`  combinations that can bring the wanted answer, and found none simple or convenient way to do this.

The solution I created is preliminary and I am sure it can be improved by the community members.

**Discounts For Locating The Process**

- The process is running on the kernel level or any other level which avoiding from the process to have an id (PID).
- The process id or the process program was not found by the output of the given commands: `lsof`, `netstat`, `ss`, `fuser`.
- We did found a listening port from the output of the above commands  - But the we cannot configure the program or the pid that causing the listening.

**About `grep`:**

We will use `grep` to find more information about the open port.

`grep` - print lines that match patterns.

From `grep` man page via `man grep` command.

```
DESCRIPTION
grep  searches  for  PATTERNS  in  each  FILE.  PATTERNS is one or more
       patterns separated by newline characters, and  grep  prints  each  line
       that  matches a pattern.  Typically PATTERNS should be quoted when grep
       is used in a shell command.
```

- [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956810/how-do-i-find-all-files-containing-specific-text-on-linux?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top) is a great topic of how use the command correctly and effectively.

**How To Locate The PID Or The Program That Using The Given Port Via `grep`:**

In my case executing `sudo grep --exclude-dir={sys,proc} -rnw / -e 51820 | grep -i port` solved the issue and showed allot information about the program that using the port.

The given output:

```
iptables.service:6:ExecStart=/usr/sbin/iptables -I INPUT -p udp --dport 51820 -j ACCEPT
/home/username/wireguard-install.sh:238:    read -p "Port [51820]: " port
/home/username/wireguard-install.sh:241:        read -p "Port [51820]: " port
/home/username/wireguard-install.sh:243:    [[ -z "$port" ]] && port="51820"
/usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/wireguard.yaml:9:      port: 51820
/etc/wireguard/wg0.conf:8:ListenPort = 51820
/etc/systemd/system/wg-iptables.service:6:ExecStart=/usr/sbin/iptables -I INPUT -p udp --dport 51820 -j ACCEPT
/etc/systemd/system/wg-iptables.service:10:ExecStop=/usr/sbin/iptables -D INPUT -p udp --dport 51820 -j ACCEPT
```

The reason for the many flags is that other combinations i have tried had a large amount of unwanted output.

**What The Arguments Of `grep` Command Stands For:**

- `--exclude-dir` - Skip any command-line directory with a name suffix that  matches
  the   pattern.

And specific ignoring `sys` and `proc` directories **in our specific case**  is to avoid unwanted output.

Example: `grep --exclude-dir={dir1,dir2}` will avoid dir1 and dir2 during the search.

- `-r` or `-R` is recursive.
- `-n` is line number.
- `-w` stands for match the whole word.
- `/` stands for the "highest" directory to start the search from top to bottom.
- `-e` - is the pattern used during the search.
- `51820` in our specific case is the port number that was found by one of the network monitoring command above.
- `|` - is the pipe to redirect the output of the first command part to the second one.

In our case: redirecting `sudo grep --exclude-dir={sys,proc} -rnw / -e 51820` output to the next command `grep -i port`

- `-i` - Ignore  case  distinctions  in  patterns and input data, so that
  characters that differ only in case match each other.
- `port` - Found in order to narrow the results to the purpose for which we performed the search, finding more information about the specific port that was defined after the `-e` flag.

**Tips:**

- Make the scan largest as possible in the first steps by starting from the `/` directory, and using minimum flags to filter the output, to ensure you won`t miss any detail which we could achieve.
- After finding the wanted output or having problems with finding the wanted output caused by allot of unwanted output, start adding flags one by one.
- Specify the port number as the pattern, after all this is our starting point and our ending goal.
- Use double `grep` commands redirecting the first scan into `port` pattern filter, it can pinpoint us and speed up the solution, after all we are looking for a number as a pattern and this can lead to many unwanted results.
- If you cannot get into conclusions with the given output, make a search over the web with a chosen key-words that you have found.

Comment: This will work for applications that use a specific port with each invocation and is listed in configuration files and such. However, NFS uses random port numbers (by default) on each invocation. See this post for more info: https://serverfault.com/a/311127/143731.

Answer (score 7):

You're running operating system that implements Wireguard as a kernel module. Your kernel is listening on this port, and since there's no process owning that socket no PID is reported by `netstat`.

Comment: How do you find out which kernel service is listening to that port?

Comment: I once spent quite some time digging the kernel code to find out if there is a way to do so and found out that the kernel records a reference to module owning a socket in the kernel socket's `proto_ops` field, but I'm not aware of the userland tools that could dump it.

Comment: Your answer is great and helped alot, if you will find out how to dump that kernel sockets and edit that to your answer i will aprove it, i voted up for the informative answer.

Comment: @CrazyTux I also looked at this and found out that the kernel does not export this information to userland. I do not think it is possible unless a kernel update provides the functionality somehow.